# Is AWS CloudFront distribution available in all edge locations?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

The S3 Bucket is located in Sydney region. This is the Origin of a CloudFront distribution I created. Will the static content be cached in all 50+ AWS Edge locations across the world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is "it depends." The static content will be cached at locations where it has been requested recently. CloudFront is a pull-through cache. When an asset is requested, the closest edge location is checked. If the asset is cached there, it is sent to the requester; if it is not, the asset is pulled from the origin and put into the edge location's cache. It will stay cached until [expiration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html). Assets that expire or are not popular enough to stay cached will be moved to regional caches. Check out the docs on [how CloudFront delivers content](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/HowCloudFrontWorks.html#HowCloudFrontWorksContentDelivery).